# SSIS Conversion Failure From Numeric Field to Date

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2-400

I have a field in an AS400 table which is a Numeric (decimal 8) field. Within this, dates are stored `YYYYMMDD` format, such as 20180518.

I then have a stage table in MS SQL Server that I am dumping this data to before processing. The destination column is of type Date.

I am having trouble getting the SSIS package to pass the values accordingly. What we've tried doing is pulling apart the numeric field as a string, and grabbing the sub-strings. Then concatenating the sections to assemble a MM/DD/YYYY formatted string.

```
substring(myfield,5,2) || '-' || substring(myfield,7,2) || '-' || substring(myfield,1,4)
```

We also tried using the Date() function on the AS400..

```
Date(substring(myfield,1,4) || '-' || substring(myfield,5,2) || '-' || substring(myfield,7,2))
```

With neither of these options working, I then tried using the SSIS conversion tool to perform the task. I changed my query back to just pull the field in, and then pass it to a data conversion tool. Within the tool, it first sees the column as a decimal.

```
[Input Column][Output Alias][Data Type]
[myfield     ][AliasMyField][decimal[DT_DECIMAL]]
```

I then changed this to be

```
[Input Column][Output Alias][Data Type]
[myfield     ][AliasMyField][date[DT_DATE]]
```

It seems no matter which avenue we attempt the package will not execute, and I keep getting:

> Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to grab any substrings.  If you insert a String in YYYYMMDD format into a SQL Server datetime field, it will insert with no problem, regardless of your regional settings.

EDIT:   A definite way to solve this is to have your dataflow import the data to a staging table that receives the 8-digit date into a varchar field without any modifications.

Then move the data to the final table using a TRY_CONVERT() to convert the varchar to a datetime, or NULL if it's unable to convert a particular value.

Comment: Yes, it should. That is why this is perplexing me, My test insert of the data throws into SQL without any issues in SMS. But then in VS2015 my dtsx refuses to run without the above error. The hacking apart and backwards way of doing things was in effort to circumnavigate the SSIS errors. It will not do a direct load from OLEDB to OLEDB without throwing that error. I added the conversion tool to try and get around it as well. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You haven't shown enough details of your dtsx to diagnose the problem.   If you have successfully converted the 8-digit number to a string, the insert shouldn't be a problem.   If SQL Server thinks it's receiving an integer, however, it would be a problem.

Comment: I don't know what else to provide for example. The DB2 select comes through as a string, "05-21-2018" (parsing the substrings, and then re-assembling into valid string date format), and then it bombs with that error. It was a direct OLEDB-OLEDB, it is the most simplistic dataflow task, and I can't elaborate on it more. Then I began using the data conversion to try and force it to a data value, and that bombs too.

Comment: What is the SSIS datatype of the field in question at every step in the dataflow?   Why are you parsing the number into a string like that when my answer is to NOT do that?

Comment: Decimal either way even when converting the values using DB2 Date(). In the preview ("05-21-2018") but the data conversion tool still sees as decimal. I even blew away the object and re-added it in case something was cached. I cannot get the DB2 field to be seen as a DATE field or even a string. I can change my target stage table and convert when migrating to proper table, and I have that as a reserve option, but the dtsx *should* be able to do this without any issues; it makes no sense why this isn't working. It seems stuck on decimal data type due to the returning field being numeric.

Comment: Go to the Advanced properties of the data source component in the dataflow, find the output column and change its SSIS datatype to a string type.

Comment: Hadn't tried that, but did not work either :/ 
I'm just going with your suggestion of alter my staging table. It doesn't make sense why this won;t work, and I can easily convert it properly while processing the stage data. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

probably have an invalid date "numbers", 20180229, 20171305, 00000000 or 99999999...

or it could be a valid date for the i, but not SQL server, 00010101 or 99991231 for instance (unless you're using the newer date or datetime2 types)

You need a function that does the conversion and catches the conversion error substitutes a valid date or returns NULL if that's acceptable.

When NULL isn't acceptable, I usually do something like

```
< 00010101 ==> 00010101  
> 99991231 ==> 99991231  
= xxxx0229 ==> xxxx0228
```

Those are the  easy ones...any others you have to decide for yourself

Comment: Yes, that is what the dates are coming through as, numeric integers as in your examples. My attempted work around was to parse the substrings of those values and assemble them as a string, convert them to a date, and then load them into the database. As in the example, substring(myfield,5,2) || '-' || substring(myfield,7,2) || '-' || substring(myfield,1,4) would then assemble to "05-21-2018" as a string value. Then it blows up. This is why it is confusing and frustrating. The a varchar value "05-21-2018" will insert into a date field without any issues, yet SSIS blows up.

Comment: @alykins, you're missing the point.  The problem is you have numbers that don't translate to a valid date.  Likely, 00000000 or 99999999.

Comment: No, they are all valid dates. They are verified as valid dates before saving on the AS400. So while they may be "invalid" because they are seen as decimal and it thinks there will be overflow, the "decimals" are all valid (like examples). This is confirmed by my end solution which is to change the stage table data type to int, and then converting to date while processing. I get no errors and can verify all dates. It is something in the dtsx not understanding to read as string values.